# PyQT5 QtSql Model Not Loading Data

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

Using the QtSql Libraries I am attempting to load data into a QTableView via the QSqlTableModel; however I get no data in the model when I call the select() method on the model:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QSize
from PyQt5.QtSql import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QTableView, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout


class SclDataBrowse(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SclDataBrowse, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(336, 462)
        self.setup_ui()
        self.setup_db()
        self.setup_model()
        self.view.setModel(self.model)
        if self.db.isOpen():
            self.load_data()

    def setup_ui(self):
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.view = QTableView(self)
        self.btn_New = QPushButton(self)
        self.btn_New.setMinimumSize(QSize(70, 21))
        self.btn_New.setMaximumSize(QSize(70, 21))
        self.btn_New.setText('New')
        self.layout.addWidget(self.view)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn_New)

    def setup_db(self):
        self.db = QSqlDatabase("QMYSQL")
        self.db.setHostName(myhost)
        self.db.setUserName(myuser)
        self.db.setPassword(mypassword)
        self.db.setDatabaseName(mydb)
        self.db.open()

    def setup_model(self):
        self.model = QSqlTableModel(self)
        self.model.setTable("scldata")
        self.model.setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel.OnManualSubmit)
        self.model.setHeaderData(0, Qt.Horizontal, 'ID')
        self.model.setHeaderData(1, Qt.Horizontal, 'Foreign ID')
        self.model.setHeaderData(2, Qt.Horizontal, 'Receipts Start')
        self.model.setHeaderData(3, Qt.Horizontal, 'Receipts End')
        self.model.setHeaderData(4, Qt.Horizontal, 'Billing Rate')

    def load_data(self):
        print('Loading Data')
        self.model.select()
        print(self.model.rowCount())
```

Is there something that I am missing here?

Comment: what is the output of `print(self.db.open())`?

Comment: `self.db.open()` returns True

Comment: `self.model.rowCount()` return 0 rows.  Verified spelling of the table and that there is data in it.

Comment: Already done - 5 rows are returned

Comment: execute: `query = QSqlQuery()
if query.exec_("select * from scldataselect"):
    print(query.size())
else:
    print("error: ", query.lastError().text())`

Comment: Interesting: `QSqlQuery::exec: database not open`  But I would have never gotten to that method if the database wasn't open.

Comment: you have to execute it you must open the database, for example in: `load_data`

Comment: But I opened the database in setup_db.  Does it not persist?

Comment: Have you added it at the end of setup_db ?, please be precise in your comments, for example I do not know where you are executing what I have pointed out to you.

Comment: Added to the end of setup_db (it's in the code that I posted).  Also interesting:  Moved the self.db.open() to the load_data() method and I get a new error: `Driver not loaded Driver not loaded`

Comment: check your connection, make a simple connection

Comment: Not sure what you mean by simple connection

Comment: I changed your code from `query=QSqlQuery()` to `query=QSqlQuery(self.db)` and the `query.size()` reported the correct number of rows returned.  This still doesn't solve my original issue though.

Comment: add `self.model.select()` after of `self.model.setTable("scldata")` and comment the lines that begin with: `self.model.setHeaderData...`

Comment: Found the issue. Looks like I need to pass the database to the `QSqlTableModel(self,self.db).  `